# sveltekit firestore crashes on page reload

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am having an issue where on my personal machine when I page reload my / the page logs no data but on the codesandbox it eventually loads. Then when I go to /profile the data loads but if I reload I get a 500 error.

I just want to load data from firestore on the +page.js page, put that data into a store and pass it to +page.svelte page. It works when I navigate between pages but when HMR or a page reload happens it reports no data or crashes.

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/thakrisp/AmmoInentory/draft/tender-galois

**+layout.svelte (root layout)**

```
    onMount(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                goto('/login');
            }
            userStore.set({ uid: user?.uid, displayName: user?.displayName, email: user?.email });
        });
    });
```

**+page.svelte (Profile page)**

```
    $: displayName = $user.displayName || 'No User';
    $: uid = $user.uid || 'Unavalible';
    $: email = $user.email || 'Unavailable';
    
    console.log($user)
```

**+page.ts (Home page)**

```
export const load: PageLoad = async () => {
    const user = getAuth().currentUser?.uid;

    if (user !== undefined) {
        const docRef = doc(db, 'ammo', `${user}`);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        const data = docSnap.data()?.ammo

        userData.set(data)

        return data
    }
}
```

**+page.Svelte (home Page)**

```
    interface userAmmo {
        name: string;
        count: number;
        grain: number;
        type: string;
    }


    export let data: PageData;
    let parsedData: userAmmo[];

    parsedData = Object.values(data);
```

I tried removing the store and loading the data onMount but on reload it logs no data. I tried reading from the store on page load but it crashes on page reload.

Comment: You dont need to initialize ```import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';``` and pass ```export const db = getFirestore(app);``` app as parameter of getFirestore() in firebase.js

Comment: This is the right way https://imgur.com/DX1kqQ8

Comment: Try wrapping the code that has the goto with if browser... because it only runs on the client.

Comment: While you are right that I am am calling GetAuth() when I should be calling auth from my firebase.js file.
None of these fixed the issue where when I reload the page the getDoc() in the +page.js isnt being run again and my store has no data.
I assume this is because store data doesnt persist on page reload 
[per this article](https://steveolensky.medium.com/persist-your-svelte-store-between-page-refreshes-in-a-few-lines-of-code-8dc36fc926a6)

Comment: This is a firebase issue. I found the same error in Nuxt 3. I'm trying to solve it too.